# Xamarin Forms Google Maps is not getting displayed on android mobile

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms

Xamarin Forms Google Map is not getting displayed on mobile. it is showing blank screen on mobile.
I am not sure what is wrong. i have given the correct Android Key and SHA1 cert also. still it is showing blank screen

Below is the code of mainpage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XApp_MAP"
             x:Class="XApp_MAP.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <maps:Map Grid.Row="1" x:Name="map"
                      InitialCameraUpdate="35.71, 139.81, 8, 30, 0"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**Android Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.xapp_map" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
    <application android:label="xappmap.android">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyA81eVj7WmkfsGqqwVnkiz32g9MBdTyxKQ" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, although I was following all steps from this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup

My problem was that the map it once showed, and then I tried again like a month after and was only showing the Google icon below.

My problem was that I switch computers, so even if my API Key was the same the SHA1 was different now, I just got it from the new pc and updated it in the Console Cloud Credentials.

After that, problem solved.

Here is a useful link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have solved your problem long ago, but I put what was my problem to maybe help someone else.

```
Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, bundle); // initialize for Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps
```

Make sure you initialize Xamarin Forms Google Maps (with that line of code above) in the method `OnCreate` inside the `MainActivity.cs` of your Xamarin Android project. Then, if you have all the configuration done correctly, it should work.